# get stuck at scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to scroll the page but the scrolling gets stuck before fetching the data.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const [page] = await browser.pages();
// test url.
await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVX_4LoUm4mdZBPdpMJkkSQ/videos', 
{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
await page.setViewport({
      width: 1200,
      height: 800
    });
 await page.evaluate(async () => {
    for (var y = 0; y < window.innerHeight; y += 200) {
      window.scrollTo(0, y);
    }});
```

Comment: i found the correct function!https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7554

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 500;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this fix your issue, and what did you change ?